# User access control in grails

Tags: grails, user-permissions

I am completely new to Grails and have done some reading on the Shiro pluggin, but im not sure it is what Im after, so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

For my final year project in Computer Science, I am creating online team collaboration tool, written in Grails.  The application is structured as follows :

Application - has many Companys using it
Companys have many projects
Projects have many users etc.

What is the best way that I ensure when a user logs in, that they can only see content for their company and projects, if they are admin, or only their projects if they are general users.  Obviously I dont want users from one company being able to access other company project information etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, there are many ways to ensure your desired behavior.

I would recommend to use shiro in combination with the standard grails filters:

```
class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {
        all(uri: "/**") {
            before = {
                // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
                if (!controllerName) return true

                accessControl {
                    // add your logic here to determine if user has access or not
                    // return true if user has access, false otherwise

                    // get current user
                    def user = yourService.getCurrentUser()
                    // get projects the user is allowed to access
                    def projects = yourService.getProjectsOfUser(user)
                    // get the project the user tries to access
                    def currentProject = Project.get(params.projectId)

                    // is current project in list of permitted projects?
                    return project.contains(currentProject)
                }
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Alternatively you could implement your own `Permission` and use `SecurityUtils.subject.isPermitted()`.

The best implementation depends on the architecture of your app. If you nee more help, you have to give some more details of your app.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, can I ask what an example of yourService would be?  would it be the likes of SpringSecurityService.getCurrentUser() ?

Comment: Never roll your own security - way too much risk in getting it wrong. Spring Security and Shiro are very easy to setup and use.

Comment: Isn't the `accessControl` closure a way of protection provided by Shiro?

Comment: I tried your example, but it removes the default permissions that are enforced on every controller and action.  My issue using the default Shiro access control, is that from what I gather, for a user to have access to `company 1`, the permission would be set as `company:*:1`, though if I have a second user, `user 2` who is part of `company 2`, and I login in as `user 1` I want the permissions to block me from getting to the URL `user\view\2`

Comment: any more help on this?  Im still not sure on how to implement permissions around keeping Company content seperate from each other, whilst hopefully retaining the default `accessControl`

Comment: Add some details about your app ... According @burt-beckwith my idea using `accessControl()` seems to be not the best.